# How to pass a custom type in to NuSoap service

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

I have a php nusoap service defined as below:

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType( 
    'OrderType', 
    'complexType', 
    'struct', 
    'all', 
    '', 
    array( 
        'OrderId' => array('name' => 'OrderId', 'type' => 'xsd:string'), 
        'CustomerNumber' => array('name' => 'CustomerNumber', 'type' => 'xsd:string'), 
    ) 
); 



$server->register("testService",
    array("OrderData" => "tns:OrderType"),
    array("return" => "tns:OrderType"), //array("return" => "xsd:string"),
    "urn:aaa",
    "urn:aaa#testService",
    "rpc",
    "encoded",
    "");
```

If I pass in the envelope as below:

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <sch:Request xmlns:sch="http://aaa.com//Schema.xsd">
        <sch:OrderId>OA1236</sch:OrderId>
        <sch:CustomerNumber>PIN555</sch:CustomerNumber>            
    </sch:Request>
</soapenv:Body>
```

How do I process the parameter $OrderData? I'd expect it to work as below but this doesn't work

```
function testService($OrderData) {                    
    $result['OrderId'] = $OrderData['OrderData'];
    $result['CusomterNumber'] = $OrderData['CustomerNumber'];
    return $result;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function testService($OrderData) {                    
    $result['OrderId'] = $OrderData['OrderId']; // OrderId instead of OrderData
    $result['CustomerNumber'] = $OrderData['CustomerNumber'];
    return $result;        
}
```